# Best practice to avoid table locks when performing hot swaps for tables in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, locking, amazon-redshift, rename

I'm running a periodic ETL process to sync tables from MySQL to Redshift. This involves table swapping - for each MySQL table I create a staging table in Redshift named `\<table>_tmp`, load data into it, and when ready I rename the production table to `\<table>_old` and rename `\<table>_tmp` to `\<table>`.

My BI platform is based on this Redshift instance, meaning that the above happens while tables may be queried (sometime by multiple queries).

Renaming a table in Redshift requires an `AccessExclusiveLock`, which can't be obtained while the table is being queried (i.e. while there are active `AccessShareLock` locks).

My concern is that my table rename will fail, time out or forever hang in case new queries will keep hitting the original table - which would mean my table-swapping logic will not hold.

Does Redshift have any locks queue that would guarantee my name change happens before new queries keep locking the table?

Otherwise - are there any other best practices to manage table swapping with Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with any database. Renaming tables causes problems when queries are in progress, and could possibly cause problems with materialized views.

An alternate method would be to **define a View** that simply queries from the table (eg `SELECT * FROM table1`).

Then, instead of renaming the tables, simply redefine the view (eg `SELECT * from table2`).

So, think of this more as a **blue/green swap** rather than promoting a table from staging to production.

Comment: Thanks @John! Does that mean that queries against a view in Redshift don't lock the view for definition changes?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd suggest trying a few scenarios to see how it behaves. Let us know what you find!

Comment: I ran some tests and it seems that view definitions can be changed while queries are actively running against them, so the blue/green suggestion holds. Thanks @John!

Comment: @Aamit Did you do anything special to make it work? I'm trying to implement the same approach (switching a view to a new table), but it seems that I cannot change the definition as long as a select query is running on the view, since it's holding some lock

Comment: @Aamit So you accepted this solution but doesn't seem to work. Year passed and Redshift has the same issue. Selecting from view also locks it and you cannot replace view while it's being locked.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, do you have any other ideas? Maybe some magical configuration that makes Redshift not lock view?